How to connect the Tor core to Android Emulator?
I want to manage for my Android Emulator in Android studio using python's lib Uiautomator2.
And I have to change IP address at the right time. I have an experience used Tor core for web-parsing, but how to connect it to my Emulator.
I looked for help on the Inthernet
